# How to use correctly NextJs API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

i've just started using Next js with mongodb and i have a question about how should i organize the API route files.

I have a simple application that add, update and delete documents of a mongodb collection. For each operation i created a `.ts` file inside the `api` folder. Like this

[image]

And for example my `new_task.ts` file looks like this

```
export default async function AddTask (req:NextApiRequest, res:NextApiResponse) {
    const task:Task = req.body
    const client = await clientPromise;
    const db = client.db("diary");
    const myCollection: Collection = db.collection('tasks');


    try {
       await myCollection.insertOne(task)
       res.send('Success')
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({error})
        console.log(error)
    }
    
}
```

Everything is working ok but i think it's kinda messy the file organization. Is there a way to put every operation inside just one file? Or to do so i would have to build a custom server with express?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one route function, you can check the request object `req` to see if the HTTP request method is GET POST PUT PATCH or DELETE. Depending on which method, you can call a different function.

Here is an [example from the NextJS docs](https://Here%20is%20an%20example.%20https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/api-routes-rest/pages/api/user/%5Bid%5D.ts).

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

export default function userHandler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const {
    query: { id, name },
    method,
  } = req

  switch (method) {
    case 'GET':
      // Get data from your database
      res.status(200).json({ id, name: `User ${id}` })
      break
    case 'PUT':
      // Update or create data in your database
      res.status(200).json({ id, name: name || `User ${id}` })
      break
    default:
      res.setHeader('Allow', ['GET', 'PUT'])
      res.status(405).end(`Method ${method} Not Allowed`)
  }
}
```

Another thing you can do to make your code more re-useable and easier to maintain is to write reusable function definitions in a lib folder and then import them into your api route files when you want to use them.

Have you tried creating a file in the `lib` folder and writing function definitions there for MongoDB and then importing those function definitions into your api route file?

Then call the appropriate function depending upon the request `method`.

In ./lib/mongodb, write a function definition and import any Mongo-related imports you need.

```
export async function updateUserInfo(parameters) {
 // . . . your code needs to return something, probably an array or object from MongoDB
}
```

In your api route file, import that function definition.

```
import { updateUserInfo } from "../../lib/mongodb"
```

Inside your route function, call `updateUserInfo` and pass whatever arguments you need based on the parameters you put in the definition. Handle its return value using `await`.

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { updateUserInfo } from "../../lib/mongodb"

export default function userHandler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const {
    query: { id, name },
    method,
  } = req

  switch (method) {
    case 'GET':
      // Get data from your database
      res.status(200).json({ id, name: `User ${id}` })
      break
    case 'PUT':
      // Update or create data in your database
      const updateResult = await updateUserInfo( . . .)
      // FIX THE OBJECT IN .JSON BELOW TO SUIT YOUR CODE
      res.status(200).json({ id, name: name || `User ${id}` })
      break
    default:
      res.setHeader('Allow', ['GET', 'PUT'])
      res.status(405).end(`Method ${method} Not Allowed`)
  }
}
```

You can reuse `updateUserInfo` anywhere you have arguments for the required parameters.

Also, consider when you are calling the API route. At build time or after. At build, you call from [static functions](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) and after you call from client-side.

So by using the lib file for function definitions, you can reuse them in server functions and static functions.

The structure of the files inside the api folder is your api architecture. So it's organization depends upon your application's needs. You can use [static](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) and [dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/dynamic-api-routes), as you maybe already know.

Consider [API best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59608660/rest-api-best-practise-for-routes) when designing your architecture.

Comment: And i can only have one function per api route file? Even if i create the create and update document function inside mongodb.js, i still need two api route files each containing one function?

Comment: Yes, however, in that one function you can check the request object `req` to see if the HTTP request `method` is `GET` `POST` `PUT` `PATCH` or `DELETE`. Depending on which method, you can call a different function. I'm editing my response above to add a code sample and link to an example.

Comment: Answer edited. Thanks for the follow up. I think it made the answer much more complete. If the answer helps you out, could you please upvote my answer?

Comment: If you don't mind i have another question. If i want to retrieve some user's documents using getServerSideProps, can i pass some params so i can retrieve only that user's document? Or because i'm using getServerSideProps  i cannot pass any params?

Comment: One thing to try is whether you can use dynamic routing. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/dynamic-api-routes. The variable in the dynamic route could be a user id that you use in getServerSideProps. You should have access there to the id from the params or context object. Another option. If the user is signed in through next-auth, you could use the server-side session object (import { unstable_getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";) to get the user id in getServerSideProps. I have to sign off for the day but good luck!